# CSS adds border to table

Tags: html, css

Please refer to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m93V4/)

The issue is in Firefox there is a border down the left side of the table and in Chrome and Safari the border goes down the right side of the table. I don't want the border down the side at all, only on the table header row.

I can't seem to get rid of it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about diagnosing this?

Here's my CSS:

```
body {background-color:black;}

table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background: url(http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/bg.gif) no-repeat 99%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background: url(http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/desc.gif) no-repeat 99%;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background: url(http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/asc.gif) no-repeat 99%;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
table.tablesorter tr.parent-row > td {

    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #253355 0%, #587993 100%);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #253355 0%, #587993 100%);
    /* Opera */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #253355 0%, #587993 100%);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #253355), color-stop(1, #587993));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #253355 0%, #587993 100%);
    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #253355 0%, #587993 100%);
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.tablesorter tr.parent-row-details > td {
    background: black;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.tablesorter-child thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #e6E66E;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 18pt;
    padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter-child tbody tr td {
    color: black;
}

table.tablesorter tbody tr.parent-row {
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: center;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.parent-row td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td.tdd { 
    horizontal-align:right;
}

.arrow-rotate {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); 
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI The 'border' appears because you have a border on the headings. This then causes it to expand the table past the rows showing the table background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border color is coming from this tag:

```
table.tablesorter {
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
}
```

If you remove it, and then get rid of the background image in this one:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
  background: url("http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/bg.gif") no-repeat scroll right center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

and then change the background color on this one to the `#CDCDCD`

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
```

You should see something like what you are looking for.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m93V4/3/)

Comment: That does get rid of the border, but I really wanted to keep that background image in "table.tablesorter thead tr .header. So, with the direction you gave me, I removed the background-color from "table.tablesorter" and I added background-color: #cdcdcd to "table.tablesorter thead tr .header" and left the image. I did not add background-color to "table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th" and it worked. The border is gone and the background image remains.

Thank you so much!! How do you go about diagnosing which part of the style is the source of the problem? Is there a tool?

Comment: I use firebug in `Firefox`. It is an Add-on for the browser. You can also right click on an item and select "Inspect Element" but the tools in Mozilla's tool box aren't as good (in my opinion) as the Firebug tool.